# Is it possible to use Eulers method for lower this initial value problem

Tags: numerical-methods

I have the following initial value problem 
$$k(x):=0.00025+10^{(6.3+0.027 \cdot x-10)}$$ 
$$s(x):= 0.0006+10^{(4.716009+0.06\cdot x-10)}$$
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = (\log(1+0.05)+s(x)+k(x))y(x)+1, y(68)=0$$
I solved this differential equation and found y(t). I evaluated in 0, ie y(0) and found a number around 10 . I would like to confirm this by using eulers method, but i have 2 problem . 
1. I'm not sure it is possible to have a starting value greater than the one i would find, 2. if I implement a one that can, I don't get the value i hoped.

My question, is it possible to use this do this? Maybe do a few iteration for me ? 
If i choose step size 0.5 im getting 
$$y(67.5) = 0+(-0.5) * (\log(1.05)+s(68)+k(68))y(68)+1)=-0.5$$
is this correct?

Comment: No it is not, I just indicate a rent of 5 percent, but I didnt realise i has no purpose here, i’ll change it

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, i am clearly operating the wrong way. 
- Can you what my flaw is in 67.5?

Comment: That's a typo, i changed it.

Comment: Im using $y_{n+1}=y_{n}+hf(t_{n},y_{n}).$

Comment: But if im using your the step size of 0.5. I seem to get y(67.5)= -0.5

Comment: Could you expand on how you exactly got the data point {67.5,−0.514618}?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72967/discussion-between-viktor-jeppesen-and-moo).